# Replace spaces in a string by another string of characters

Tags: awk, sed, replace

I have a text file containing values as follow:

```
<data>
   <values=11.0200004578 -1.17999994755 -16.1200008392 />
   <values=97.0999984741 -0.449999988079 2.16000008583 />
   <values=41.7299995422 60.6699981689 43.75 />
</data>
```

I am trying to get it as this:

```
<data>
   <values A="11.0200004578" B="-1.17999994755" C="-16.1200008392 />
   <values A="97.0999984741" B="-0.449999988079" C="2.16000008583 />
   <values A="41.7299995422" B="60.6699981689" C="43.75 />
</data>
```

For the first part, it's easy, it is just a sed replacement

```
sed 's#<values=#<values A="#'
```

But I cannot manage to find a way for the other values.

Comment: btw closing quote is missing at the end of each line

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hardcoding attributes `A, B, C` etc you may use this `awk` solution that generated these values from ASCII code:

```bash
awk -F= '
$1 ~ /<values$/ && (n=split($2, a, /[[:blank:]]+/)) {
   s = ""
   ch = 0
   for (i=1; i<n; ++i)
      s = s sprintf("%c=\"%s\" ", 65+ch++, a[i])
   $2 = s a[n]
} 1' file

<data>
   <values A="11.0200004578" B="-1.17999994755" C="-16.1200008392" />
   <values A="97.0999984741" B="-0.449999988079" C="2.16000008583" />
   <values A="41.7299995422" B="60.6699981689" C="43.75" />
</data>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(=)([[:digit:].-]+) ([[:digit:].-]+) ([[:digit:].-]+)/ A\1"\2" B\1"\3" C\1"\4"/' input_file
<data>
   <values A="11.0200004578" B="-1.17999994755" C="-16.1200008392" />
   <values A="97.0999984741" B="-0.449999988079" C="2.16000008583" />
   <values A="41.7299995422" B="60.6699981689" C="43.75" />
</data>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always have 3 values A,B, and C you can match the whole tag and use capture groups to retrieve the values. In sed syntax I think it is:

`s#<values=\(\d+\.?\d*\) \(\d+\.?\d*\) \(\d+\.?\d*\) />#<values A="\1" B="\2" C="\3" />#`